# Difference between $scope.myFunction() and myFunction($scope)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm currently developping an angular app and I have found two ways to call a function that does a simple multiplication.

First

```
    function calcul(contexte) {
        contexte.proposition.marge_theorique = contexte.proposition.marge_grille * 2;
    }
```

and call it with

```
calcul($scope)
```

Second

```
    $scope.dynamicChange = function () {
        $scope.proposition.marge_theorique = $scope.proposition.marge_grille * 2;
    }
```

and call it with

```
$scope.dynamicChange()
```

What is the difference between those usages?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no execution difference between your two approaches, but I would recommend you the second one, cause passing scope in parameter is not very usual, adds nothing, and it not allows you to use method directly in your view.

Using the second way, (I mean, the `$scope.dynamicChange` one), is also good cause you take profit of the Angular controllers inheritance. So every child scope of your controller scope will get this method.

Conclusion, no very difference for your specific task, but I recommend you to use the more "Angular" way.

Answer (score 0):

In the example above, calling the function with `dynamicChange()` would throw an error, since `dynamicChange()` is a *method of $scope* and not a function.

You would need to call `$scope.dynamicChange`

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to call the function of the first example from within your html-templates.
So you can't just use something like.

```
<div>
  {{myFunction()}}
</div>
```